# Why is CSharpOptParse UsageBuilder failing due to an XPathException only when used in an NUnit test?

Tags: c#, xslt, nunit, csharpoptparse

What is the root cause of this issue? CSharpOptParse, XslTransform.Transform(...), or NUnit? What other equivalent library could I use instead, if this problem is unfixable, that is being actively supported?

I'm using version 1.0.1 of [CSharpOptParse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csharpoptparse) which was last modified in Feb 2005.

I've have the following class (simplified for this example of course) to use along with CSharpOptParse:

```
public enum CommandType
{
   Usage
}

public class Options
{
   [OptDef(OptValType.Flag)]
   [LongOptionName("help")]
   [Description("Displays this help")]
   public bool Help { get; set; }

   public CommandType CommandType
   {
      get { return CommandType.Usage; }
   }
}
```

Here is a bit of unit test code that replicates the issue:

```
TextWriter output = Console.Out;

Options options = new Options { Help = true };
Parser p = ParserFactory.BuildParser(options);
p.Parse();

output.WriteLine("Usage: Console [--a]");
UsageBuilder builder = new UsageBuilder();
builder.BeginSection("Arguments:"); 
builder.AddOptions(p.GetOptionDefinitions()); //could the issue be created here?
builder.EndSection();
builder.ToText(output, OptStyle.Unix, true); //The problem occurs here
```

Is it possible that I'm causing the problem by not setting up the UsageBuilder with the correct sections? Possibly this might be causing problems in the xslt file???

When I run that code I get the following exception:

```
    System.Xml.XPath.XPathException : Function 'ext:FormatText()' has failed.
    ----> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
      ----> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
    Parameter name: startIndex
       at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.FunctionQuery.Evaluate(XPathNodeIterator nodeIterator)
       at System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.Processor.ValueOf(ActionFrame context, Int32 key)
       at System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.ValueOfAction.Execute(Processor processor, ActionFrame frame)
       at System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.ActionFrame.Execute(Processor processor)
       at System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.Processor.Execute()
       at System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.Processor.Execute(TextWriter writer)
       at System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform.Transform(XPathNavigator input, XsltArgumentList args, TextWriter output, XmlResolver resolver)
       at System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform.Transform(IXPathNavigable input, XsltArgumentList args, TextWriter output, XmlResolver resolver)
       at CommandLine.OptParse.UsageBuilder.ToText(TextWriter writer, OptStyle optStyle, Boolean includeDefaultValues, Int32 maxColumns)
--TargetInvocationException
    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
    at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
    at System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.XsltCompileContext.FuncExtension.Invoke(XsltContext xsltContext, Object[] args, XPathNavigator docContext)
    at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.FunctionQuery.Evaluate(XPathNodeIterator nodeIterator)
    --ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    at System.String.LastIndexOfAny(Char[] anyOf, Int32 startIndex, Int32 count)
```

I have no idea what is causing this problem....and the weirdest part is that is only occurs within my NUnit test. When this code is called via "Console.exe --help" it runs fine with no exceptions. I can't see anything wrong with CSharpOptParse so could this be a problem in .NET's XslTransform class or in NUnit?

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Does anyone have any advice on how to track down the issue or switch to a better library?

Comment: I've yet to find an answer to this question...and I don't think I'd get much of a response if I put a bounty on it. Does anyone out there know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question. But..

The exception is caused because the `ToText()` method tries to determine the width of the console and it fails when you're writing to anything that is not a real console.

The fix is simple: Set a fixed width.

Change the call to ToText to:

```
try
{
    usage.ToText(Console.Out, OptStyle.Unix, true);
}
catch
{
    usage.ToText(Console.Out, OptStyle.Unix, true, 90);
}
```

Now if the normal call fails, it will try a fail-safe one.

Comment: Sorry to have taken so long to reply...been a while since I've had to deal with that problem...but I can confirm that what you've said is the case and it does fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you attach a debugger to NUnit, turn on First-Chance exceptions, and find out what's going on?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that. I only know how to attach the debugger to my project... The best I know how to do is step through the code in the debug window...but the exception occurs in a location that I can't step into. If you can enlighten me, that would be excellent.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and have seemed to have fixed it (not sure of the issues it would cause doing this but everything seems to work okay).

Find:

```
public TextTransformHelper(int maxColumns)
        {
            _maxColumns = maxColumns;

            if (_maxColumns == -1)
            {
                // try to determine console width
                string os = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OS");

                if (os != null && os.StartsWith("Win"))
                {
                    ConsoleUtils.ConsoleHelper ch = new ConsoleUtils.ConsoleHelper();
                    _maxColumns = ch.GetScreenInfo().Size.X;
                }
            }
        }
```

and then modify it to the following:

```
public TextTransformHelper(int maxColumns)
    {
        _maxColumns = maxColumns;

        if (_maxColumns == -1)
        {
            // try to determine console width
            string os = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OS");

            if (os != null && os.StartsWith("Win"))
            {
                ConsoleUtils.ConsoleHelper ch = new ConsoleUtils.ConsoleHelper();
                _maxColumns = ch.GetScreenInfo().Size.X;
                if(_maxColumns == 0) //added
                    _maxColumns = -1; //added
            }
        }
    }
```

The reason it was blowing up was because in the FormatText function it has the following if statement which was supposed to be hit if a columnwidth was not defined or was -1.  The function for me would always return 0 which would cause the below if statement to not get hit and then cause an "ArgumentOutOfRange" exception.  This was on Windows Server 2008:

```
if (_maxColumns == -1)
                {
                    output.Append((first) ? indentStr : handingIndentStr);
                    output.Append(line);
                    output.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    first = false;
                    continue;
                }
```

I was able to debug it by seeing the "ext:FormatText" failed error and then setting breakpoints on all FormatText functions (the xslt was calling the C# function) and then looking at the exception and debugging in further.

I hope this helps.

John Rennemeyer