# What alternatives exist for CSharpOptParse?

Tags: c#, equivalent, csharpoptparse

I've [previously asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486119/why-is-csharpoptparse-usagebuilder-failing-due-to-an-xpathexception-only-when-use) about an issue I have been experiencing with [CSharpOptParse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csharpoptparse) that didn't get much of a response. Since I haven't been able to resolve the issue, I'm looking around for an alternative library.

While the issue I'm experiencing isn't really enough of a compulsion for me to search for an alternative...the fact that the last development for this library was done in 2005 worries me a bit.

Does anyone know of any good equivalent C# command line option parsing library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono distribute a library in the form of a single source file to simply place inline in your own projects called Mono.Options since 2.2 as the suggested replacement for Mono.GetOptions

This is basically [NDesk.Options](http://www.ndesk.org/Options) and it works just fine in MS.Net too.

CodePlex has a variety of libraries (of varying levels of development) active ones include:

- [ConsoleFX](http://www.codeplex.com/ConsoleFx)
- [commandline](http://www.codeplex.com/commandline)
- [CmdLine](http://www.codeplex.com/cmdline)
- [CommandLineHelper](http://www.codeplex.com/CommandLineHelper)